# Index Server: Truly not available on Windows 2012?

Tags: windows

I have been given a project to move an important .asp app to win2012 (currently on win2003). This app uses Index Server (It uses the OLE DB provider to access Index Server.

```
Set ixQuery = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

ixQuery.Open "provider=msidxs;Data Source=knowledgestore"
```

My research so far indicates that Index Server is no longer possible/available on win2012.

Is that true?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The replacement to Index Server is actually "Windows Search Service" which is built in to Windows.

Note the name: Windows Search **Service** There is another tool, Windows Search **Server** *which is a different animal entirely*.

No download required. Windows Search **Service** is part of the Win2008 and Win2012 (and Windows 7 & 8) OSes.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24567543/147637

Also:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965362(v=vs.85).aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/olavt/archive/2007/05/07/howto-enable-windows-search-service-in-longhorn-server.aspx

http://www.cloudtec.ch/blog/tech/add-search-indexed-network-share-windows-library.html

Comment: `Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Microsoft Indexing Service` is MSIDXS . Windows Search Server is the same Microsoft Indexing Service?   How use ***Search Service*** and _ASP.NET_ ?

Comment: Downvote for not accepting Ryan's answer. Seriously, you should have accepted his answer instead of posting your own.

Answer (score 7):

Microsoft Indexing Service is gone. Steady march of progress. From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms689646%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Note  Indexing Service is no longer supported as of Windows XP and **is unavailable for use as of Windows 8.** Instead, use Windows Search for client side search and Microsoft Search Server Express for server side search.

Note that the above information, from Microsoft site, is INCORRECT. The parallel, replacement, technology for Index Server is the Search **Service** (NOT Search Server Express, which is a bigger, different animal).

You'll have to convert to Windows Search Service, which is the replacement for Index Server, and is part of the Windows OS. (Note, Microsoft Search Server has a very similar name, and feature set, but is a different animal).

Notice the *"no longer supported as of Windowx XP,"* which means you've been rollin' on some very old tech.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/23742531/147637 for how to install the Windows Search Service.

Comment: Ryan, Your answer is almost correct. The real replacement for index server is "Windows Search Service"  -- even the MS docs you reference are incorrect. (Crazy, I agree! That is what they get for having two similar products with nearly identical names!)

Comment: Indexing Service is no longer supported as of Windows XP and is unavailable for use as of Windows 8. Instead, use *Windows Search for client side search and Microsoft Search Server Express for server side search*.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee805985(v=vs.85).aspx